# How to detect in Angular 14 that we have opened a new tab( on reload of the second tab)?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am searching for a way how to detect that second tab is opened while reloading the second tab and first tab should be open

User Story :

There are two tabs - tab1 and tab2

copy paste the url from tab1 and create tab2

make some changes in tab1

Changes in tab1 are getting pushed in localStoage

changes should be reflected in tab2 while reloading through notification

Any idea how to proceed for this

I am trying with PageVisibility  API / BroadCastChannel . not helping

Any idea how to proceed for this ?

Comment: Use broadcast channel you can solve the problem